# Cómo marcar un texto obtenido cómo javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de mostrar información ingresada en el input que es un json pero no me muestra nada, solo un undefined, qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var a = document.querySelector(".text");
var b = document.querySelector(".button");

b.onclick = function() {

var t = [a.value];

alert(t[0].by); // UNDEFINED

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text" value="{'by': 'Name', 'lge': 'es'}">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Enviar">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. El valor del input `.text` debe ser un texto que contenga un json válido. Fíjate como se usan las comillas dobles `"` para envolver los valores.
2. El valor debe convertirse a un objeto javascript para poder acceder a sus propiedades, eso se hace con `JSON.parse`

```js
var a = document.querySelector(".text");
var b = document.querySelector(".button");

b.onclick = function() {

var t = [JSON.parse(a.value)];

alert(t[0].by); // UNDEFINED

}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="text" value='{"by": "Name", "lge": "es"}'>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Enviar">
```